# Cannot import pathos in Python

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, pathos

```
import pathos
import pathos.multiprocessing as mp
import dill
print pool.map(pow, [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8])
```

when i run the above code it throws a error

> cannot find pathos.multiprocessing
>
> cannot import pathos

i tried all the possible ways but i could not find any solution. I was trying to work on a developing a code which takes more than 10 inputs and process them using multiprocessing instead of waiting in queue and generates output. For that i have tried multiprocessing, but it throws pickling error, so i tried to use pathos, but it says cannot import pathos. Can any one tell me the possible solution for this???

Comment: Did you install pathos?

Comment: No i just imported, i have inbuilt python package called pathwise

Comment: if one of the below answers is working for you  please "select" and "accept" it. If you solved it differently please post your answer to complete the Question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `pip` installed (and `git`), you can simply type the following at in a command shell (dos, bash, or similar… not a python interpreter):

```
>$ pip install setuptools
>$ pip install git+https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos.git@master
```

This will install `pathos` and all of it's dependencies on linux-type systems. If you are on windows, then you'll need a C++ compiler, like MS Visual Studio Community.  Here's instructions if you have `conda`:

```
>$ conda install pip
>$ conda install setuptools
>$ pip install git+https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos.git@master
```

There is more detailed instructions here:

https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos/issues/2

https://github.com/mmckerns/tuthpc

Answer (score 0):

You need to install it in order to use it. Go to the `Pathos` website and download it:
http://trac.mystic.cacr.caltech.edu/project/pathos/wiki/Installation

Then you can navegate to the folder and install it via shell using Python itself:

```
python setup.py install
```

Then, try to `import Pathos` and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

You need to **install** the software you use, otherwise you can't use it.

So, go ahead and install pathos.

Comment: How do i install pathos in different environments, i am using visual studios and analytic studios.

Comment: I don't know either IDE; so you should probably consult the documentation for that. Usually, you use your package manager (if you're using a good development OS), or you'll have to go through the easy_install/pip way (especially if you're unfortunate enough to be bound to windows)

Comment: I am using Python Pathwise analytic studio and Visual Studio, i have inbuilt  packages and couldn`t find any  of the pathos in that package

Comment: This answer is unhelpful. It is unclear, especially to newer users that it can't be "installed" from Anaconda Navigator. Also there is no description of how to install or a pointer to how to.